# How to connect app Android with amf web services?

Tags: android, eclipse, apache-flex, amf

I want to write and read to web service `AMF`. I tried import `flex-messaging-core.jar` and `flex-messaging-common.jar` but Eclipse give me the next error:

```
Eclipse: (Android 2.2)
...... Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: flex/messaging/version.properties
Origin 1: ......\android\flex-messaging-core.jar
Origin 2: ......\android\flex-messaging-common.jar
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.classpath` and `.project` file and creating the eclipse project from the scratch?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dataservicesjee/4.6/Developing/WS4976f0ec3ef48246-1c24bbe312dc391a64f-8000.html#WS4976f0ec3ef48246-44c8a7a912dc3bcf6f2-8000) you need to use `flex-messaging-client-android.jar`.  Once I started using that file instead of the separate includes it worked fine.