# connect android with AMF webservices

Tags: android, web-services, amf

I'm having some trouble finding documentation of how to communicate an android app with AMF.

This post is related to this post [How to connect app Android with amf web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992095/how-to-connect-app-android-with-amf-web-services). I've seen the Adobe post but is helpless in my case.

I was using flex-messaging-common and flex-messaging-core in my swing application and want to do the same in android, but the classes are different (eg: AMFConnection doesn't exists) and couldn't find anywhere how to do the same.

Is there any tutorial, documentation or something else than the link in Adobe ?.

Comment: It's no different than using AMF in an AIR project or a Web project.  In many cases, you'll just compile the services-config into your app using the services compiler argument.  Without knowing what you're doing; I'm not understanding what classes are different.  RemoteObject works fine in a Flex mobile project.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with Flex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else has the same problem, I finally ended up using [Klio library](http://code.google.com/p/klio-mobile-dataservice/) and everything worked just fine.

Comment: How can you add new objects to be encoded and decoded and the farthest i can get using it is an error while calling remote method, its a ClientStatusException message: java.io.EOFException code:AMFConnection.Call.Failed

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You could use the same DataType in both sides (eg: create a project that contains these classes and use it in both projects), or you could parse the response. The response will be sent as an ASObject or a collection of ASObjects. An ASObject is basically a HashMap with key = fieldName and value = fieldValue.

Comment: Could You please provide more information how to cast object received from amf channel to target object? 
When I cast it like this: `User wrapper = (User) result;`
I get: **java.lang.ClassCastException: flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject**
When I try `ActionScriptDecoder dec = DecoderFactory.getDecoder(result, User.class);  Object o = dec.decodeObject(result, User.class);` or `ASTranslator translator = new ASTranslator();  User user = (User) translator.convert(result, User.class);`
I get **flex.messaging.MessageException: TYPE_NOT_FOUND. TYPE_NOT_FOUND**